# Django tell if last item with certain attribute in dual ordering (order_by)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

In a Django queryset how can I tell if the list item I'm on (when iterating) is the list item that has a certain attribute.

Example: I order a queryset by:

```
  MyModel.objects.all().order_by('-featured', '-created_at')
```

So, all objects which are featured first by their appropriate time and then all non-featured items sorted by time properly as well.

When iterating in the template I want to be able to tell if I've hit the last "featured" item in the dual-ordering (such that featured = True).

Example usage: If last item -> display banner separating featured / non-featured -> continue iterating displaying non-featured after banner.

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    # display object
    {% if last item with attribute %} 
          # display banner
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I know I can do another queryset to get the count, but that's an extra query I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the items in the queryset using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) before passing it to the template. Then you'll show the banner when the group key changes from `True` to `False`:

```
from itertools import groupby

qs = MyModel.objects.all().order_by('-featured', '-created_at')
grouped_qs = groupby(qs, lambda x: x.featured)
```

And then in your template:

```html
{% for k, g in grouped_qs %}
   {% if not k %}
       <!- show banner -->
   {% endif %}

   {% for model_obj in g %}
       <!- do something with model_obj -->
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Doesn't this mess up the time ordering which I have to preserve?

Comment: @Overflow2341313 No it doesn't.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the solution. Will accept when I can.

Comment: Is there any reason pagination would break this? I tried iterating using a copy of the queryset (since pagiantion doesn't work on groupby) passed as a context variable and when iterating only one object shows out of the group.

Comment: Django caches the iterators / iterates over them. SO, the solution was to convert it to a list before django does. This prevents the data from being lost in the template.